# Basic understanding of webos architecture

Tags: web-applications, architecture, kernel, middleware, webos

I am new to webos , so i want to get basic understand of webos architecture. I have read many documentations regarding webos but not getting proper idea about its organisation and interaction among varoius components like application to middleware and kernel components.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you would have visited http://www.openwebosproject.org/docs/architecture/#.UfoxTY3-JfA ,if not please do so and I am sure it will help. It would be better if you ask any specific question here. Thanks.